# Modeling XML edge case in haskell data structure

Tags: xml, haskell, structure, modeling

I am trying to read data from an xml file with the following format:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <dataType>number</dataType>
        <name>two</name>
        <data>2</data>
        <group>even numbers</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <dataType>number</dataType>
        <name>three</name>
        <data>3</data>
        <group>odd numbers</group>
        <items>
            <item>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <name>four</name>
                <data>4</data>
                <group>even numbers</group>
            </item>
            <item>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <name>five</name>
                <data>5</data>
                <group>odd numbers</group>
            </item>
        </items>
    </item>
</items>
```

Into a haskell data structure so that i could manipulate the data in the data structure. Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs

data Item = Item { datatype :: String
                  ,name :: String
                  ,data1 :: Integer
                  ,group :: String
                   }

  deriving (Show, Eq)


main :: IO ()
main = do  
  menu


menu :: IO ()
menu = do 

  items <- runX (readDocument [withValidate no] "data.xml" 
                >>> getitem)
  print items
  



getitem :: ArrowXml cat => cat (NTree XNode) Item     
getitem = deep (isElem >>> hasName "item" ) >>> 
  proc x -> do
    datatype1 <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "dataType") -< x
    name1 <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "name") -< x
    dat <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "data") -< x
    let dat1 = read dat :: Integer
    group1 <- getText <<< getChildren <<< deep (hasName "group") -< x

    returnA -< Item { datatype = datatype1, name = name1, data1 = dat1, group = group1 }
```

The data not being read into the structure properly after it reaches the edge case in the second item tag that contains the number 3. Please help :(.

```
[Item {datatype = "number", name = "two", data1 = 2, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = 
"odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name 
= "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 
= 4, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"}]
```

that is the output i receive. when it should be :

```
[Item {datatype = "number", name = "two", data1 = 2, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "three", data1 = 3, group = "odd numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "four", data1 = 4, group = "even numbers"},Item {datatype = "number", name = "five", data1 = 5, group = "odd numbers"}]
```

Comment: What part of the XML do you consider to be an "edge case"? It all looks like ordinary conventional XML to me.

Comment: the second <item> tag contains an <items> tag with two other items inside. when the data is read into my data model everything reads fine until it reaches that part. then the entire output gets mixed up. I've added the out put to my question

Comment: Recursion isn't an edge case, it is the general case. XML is intrinsically recursive, it's non-recursive documents that are the special case. I'm afraid I don't know Haskell but I would have thought that Haskell data structures were also naturally recursive, and that it's easy enough to convert one recursive data structure to another using a recursive function.